# How to Iteratively Create Tensorflow Graphs On The Fly Without Accumulating Memory?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

What is the idiomatic way to construct a new neural network during each iteration of the training loop? It is an unusual thing to do, but I am working on an unusual project.

The tensorflow API documentation says "A session may own resources, such as variables, queues, and readers. It is important to release these resources when they are no longer required. To do this, either invoke the close() method on the session, or use the session as a context manager.", so my first attempt involved declaring all my tensorflow variables within a session context manager, so that they can be freed at the next iteration of the training loop:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
     while step * train_batchsize < training_iters:
         with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
             X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 227 * 227 * 3])

             y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nclasses])
             # mkoptimize is my function which constructs the neural network.
             weights,biases,optimizer,accuracy,cost,conv1,conv2,dense1 = mkoptimize(X_placeholder,y_placeholder,table,npyweights,npybiases,nclasses)
             feed = {X_placeholder : X.reshape((train_batchsize,227 * 227 * 3)), y_placeholder : gt, keep_prob: dropout}
             sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed)
             npyweights = {k : sess.run(v).flatten() for k,v in weights.items()}
             npybiases = {k : sess.run(v).flatten() for k,v in biases.items()}
             # manually modify npyweights and npybiases according to some ensemble methods, and do some other things of interest.
             feed_acc = {X_placeholder: xs.reshape((test_batchsize,227 * 227 * 3)), y_placeholder: gt, keep_prob: 1.}
             sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
             acc = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=feed_acc)
```

The first iteration of the training loop executes correctly, but on the second iteration the call to `tf.initialize_all_variables()` leads to a memory error "ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB." Does exiting the session context not in fact free memory in the graph? Each iteration of the loop involves the same amount of data and the same number of parameters in the neural network, so I don't think it's my construction that leads to the memory error.

The documentation is not very detailed on what exactly `tf.reset_default_graph` does, but I've tried freeing memory by calling  at the end of the session, leading to the error:

```
File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 706, in __exit__
   context_manager.__exit__(exec_type, exec_value, exec_tb)
   File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
   File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2978, in get_controller
    assert self.stack[-1] is default
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I iteratively create tensorflow graphs without accumulating memory?

Comment: what if you do `tf.reset_default_graph` between `while step` and `with tf.Session` lines?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I did end up doing that, and I still end up with memory errors over time (only now it is RAM instead of GPU memory being exhausted and it takes about 50 iterations until all memory is filled). The temporary hack I've settled on for now is to periodically save work and wrap the python program in a shell script with an infinite loop that restarts my program again once the kernel kills the process.

Comment: Hm...sounds like a bug. We had a similar one for GPU RAM not being released https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1727 . If you get a self-contained example that can be run to show the problem it would  be worth filing a bug on github

Comment: Hi @seewalker, Did you figure out how to do it? I have an unusual project as well. that I need to create a graph on the fly at every iteration. My network has some shared variables that every time creates a new graph using those variables. But with my current implementation the graph grows at every iteration until at some point kernel kills it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, as it was already said in the comments, you are adding to the same graph in each iteration. You should use a clean graph every time. `tf.reset_default_graph()` is one option, but maybe a more clean way is to make it explicit, like this:

```
while step * train_batchsize < training_iters:
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
      with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
        # ...
```

If you then end up with GPU memory problems, this is covered by [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1727) (as indicated by the comments), which says that it is actually a bug in the Nvidia drivers and an update to the Nvidia drivers should fix it.